# study for exam, looking for explanation. pthread_join. what is this code doing?

Tags: pthreads

I am looking at this piece of code:

```
/* 04-join.c

Simple illustration of dividing work among two threads

pthread.h should be first otherwise compile with -D_THREAD_SAFE 
*/
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
   int *ar;
   long n;
   int id;
   int sum;
} subarray;


void *incer(void *arg) {
  long i;
   int id = ((subarray*)arg)->id;

   printf("Start thread: %d sum=%ld\n",id, ((subarray*)arg)->sum);
   for (i = 0; i < ((subarray*)arg)->n; i++) {
      ((subarray*)arg)->ar[i]++;
      ((subarray*)arg)->sum++;
   }
   printf("Terminating thread: %d sum=%ld\n",id, ((subarray*)arg)->sum);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
   int ar[1000000];
   pthread_t th1, th2;
   subarray sb1, sb2;

   sb1.ar = &ar[0];
   sb1.n  = 500000;
   sb1.id = 1;
   sb1.sum = 0;
   pthread_create(&th1, NULL, incer, &sb1);

   sb2.ar = &ar[500000];
   sb2.n  = 500000;
   sb2.id = 2;
   sb2.sum = 0;
   pthread_create(&th2, NULL, incer, &sb2);

   pthread_join(th1, NULL);
   pthread_join(th2, NULL);
   printf("Terminating main: %d sum=%d\n",getpid(),sb1.sum+sb2.sum);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return 0;
}
```

My question is, in the function incer in the for loop. We have the piece of code

```
((subarray*)arg)->ar[i]++;
```

In the subarry struct ar is a pointer to a integer, correct? So what does ar[i]++ do? Why is it being done? Is it simulating "work done" by this thread, along with incrementing the sum?

Also one more small question. What is the purpose of "void *" in front of incer? I missed the part about the importance of void *.

Does it mean that, this pointer points to the address of the incer function. And by creating the function a void * called "incer" is created and we can use it to refer to this section of code when creating the thread, so it knows to execute this section of code?

Also, why pthreads? process-threads?

Comment: "p" in "pthreads" mean "POSIX".

Answer (score 0):

Incer being declared with a return type of void* allows it to return a value when it exits, which is then retrieved by pthread_join'ing the thread. The return value would likely have to be allocated on the heap and cast to (void*). In this case the thread is returning no value and the main process is not expecting a return value as pthread_join is being called with a NULL argument.

ar can be a pointer to a single integer, but it can also be a pointer to an array of integers. In this case, it's an array of integers.

((subarray*)arg)->ar[i]++; is incrementing the integer at index i by 1.

Comment: So int *ar basically should look like, for it to makes sense to me, int *ar[]? -- So in incer when a return statement is reached and evaluated, it is placed on the heap, and how does it notify main process or calling process it has a return value, does the calling process, as it is waiting, constantly check for a return value so it can do something? -- So this piece of code places a 1 at each index of int ar[100k] and adds one to the sum each time, then reports the sum of 100k each run, everytime; because of the pthread_join calls?